# Clicking, pressing-down, and releasing a button

Tags: android, button

I have a button in my android studio project and I want the button to perform three different action. First, when it is clicked. Secondly, when it is hold down and lastly, when it is released. I tried using onTouch listener:

```
    button.setOnTouchListener (new View.OnTouchListener){
        @Override 
        public void onTouch (MotionEvent motionEvent)
            switch (motionEvent.getAction ()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //record video
                return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //stop record
                    return true;

            }
                return true;
        }
    }

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener){
            @Override 
            public void onClick (View view){
                //capture image
            }
        }
```

The problem Is, when the button is tapped once it produces an execption and causes my app to crash

Answer (score -1):

onTouchListener should be to help out, and the code below should be able to:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {        
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // PRESSED
            return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // RELEASED
            return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
    }
    return false;
}
```

});

Comment: What did you change from the original code? Explaining what you changed and *why* it should help would be better. For example, where did `view` come from?

Comment: Do you mind posting the exception error please, because that piece of code work fine my android app.